# I get error on system line C++

Tags: c++, pause

I have a very simple program written in C++, see it here:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
cout<<"Simple message"<<endl;
system("msg * test message");
return 0;
}
```

When I try to compile this script using command: `g++ 1.cpp -o test.exe`, I get error:

```
1.cpp: In function 'int main()':
1.cpp:6:29: error: 'system' was not declared in this scope
  system("msg * test message");
                         ^
```

I checked code, but I can't find the reason of this error, should I change the compiler or is there mistake in in this code?

Comment: Are you attempting a log?

Comment: You should **use google.**

Comment: *very simple script* -- Man I hate that term "script" for a C++ program.  You're writing a program, not a "script".

Comment: I used google, but I could not found anything useful.

Comment: @ZviadGabroshvili http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/system

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie thanks for correction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`system()` is defined in `stdlib.h` (or `cstdlib` for C++).

```
#include <cstdlib>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the library header that the `system` function is found in.

Add this to the top:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

Comment: Well, _library_ isn't quite the correct term. _"Header file"_ would be better.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ would you prefer header? Fixed.

Comment: Yes, as mentioned. `system()` itself doesn't need to add further libraries than already linked with the c++ standard settings.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I am aware.. didn't think that word choice confused the answer at all.